# How do experience points work in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, on two separate profiles, I have noticed that after I kill something like a Mammoth or a Draugr Deathlord, I'm not gaining any experience. So my question is, do you gain experience by levelling up perks only, or is it a mixture of levelling perks and damage dealt in combat?

Also, I have a console and it took me a week to get from level 43 to level 44, whereas my friend took only a single day. How can I quickly level up?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. The answers are not the same, and the question is different: this one they don't understand the basics and are asking what the basics are, whereas in the other Q they do understand and they're asking how to maximise the levelling system. The other Q probably needs a title edit to make it reflect the *actual* question asked and sound less generic (and more obviously not a dup). It's only superficially similar, and far from "exact."

Answer (score 2):

The Elder Scrolls games are somewhat unusual in that there are no experience points and you do not level in a traditional manner. Rather than receiving experience for killing monsters or completing quests, your level is increased by improving your skills.

For example, damaging enemies with a dagger or long sword increases your One-Handed Weapons skill whereas stealing items from enemies increases your Pickpocket skill. After a certain number of skill increases, the game gives you a level-up. Weapons skills (Archery, One-Handed Weapons, Two-Handed Weapons, Destruction magic) are increased by dealing damage with their respective weapons; kills are not necessary.

You can only increase your level by improving skills, regardless of whether you put points into perks or not.

As for your leveling speed, it is most likely because your friend branched out into leveling new skills. If you have played with a certain type of weapon (Two-handed, for example), it takes progressively more time to level that skill. Your friend probably decided to level a different skill and thus his level increased more quickly.

Comment: He's thinking like he plays ESO, because what you mentioned in the first paragraph is the way to gain XP in ESO. You know killing mobs and completing quests to gain them.